# Api do Facebook com Javascript SDK esta retornando somente nome e id

Tags: javascript, api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Olá,
Estou tentando utilizar a api do facebook para fazer Login em uma determinada pagina , deu tudo certo , mas o retorno dos dados pega somente um objeto com name e id , li alguns artigos e vi que o objeto normalmente retorna : `{name: ,id: , email: , comments: , likes: , pictures: }` , alguem sabe como resolver isso ?

Segue meu código Js:

```
function callbackMudancaStatus(response){
        // O objeto de resposta é retornado com o campo de status
        //que faz com que o aplicativo saiba o status de login do usuario
        if(response.status === 'connected'){
            //caso o usuario esteja logado, execute minha api
            //trazendo as informações dele
            $('.login').hide().fadeOut(1000);
            $('#status').append('<a onclick="LogarOff()" style="cursor:pointer"> Sair </a>');
            testAPI();
        }else if(response.status === 'not_authorized'){
            //caso estiver logada no face , mas não na pagina
            $('#status').html('<p>Por favor, faça login na pagina</p>');
        }else{
            //não esta logado nem no face e nem na pagina
            //logo é impossivel trazer as informações
            //- $('#status').html('<p>Por favor faça login no facebook</p>');
        }
    }
    //facebookInicializaçãoAssincrona
    //significa que esta é a função de inicializaçao da API
    //Isso é o que carrega quando se entra nesta pagina
    window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
      //inicia a Api do face
      FB.init({
          //A sua ID de desenvolvedor
          appId:'{minha-id}',
          //Permitr cookie ,  é necessario que ele permita
          //para criar os cookies de conexões dos usuarios
          cookie:true,
          //da permissão para usar os plugins do face ,como por exempo
          //o botão de login que esta na documentação
          //você não é obrigado a chamar esse atributo
          xfbml:true,
          //por ultimo a versão da API
          version: 'v2.5' //sem isso a api não funciona
      });

      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
          //A resposta do getLoginStatus vai ser
          //a função de callback que fizemos no começo
          //feito isso ele faz a verificação de conexão com o facebook
          //e caso haja conexão , ele executa o testAPI()
          callbackMudancaStatus(response);
      });
    };
    //Codigo do facebook para inicialização do 
    //JavaScript SDK
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    //Função de inicializar a API
    function testAPI(){
      //- URL de onde quer trazer os dados
      //- /me no caso seria /eu <- o usuario que esta fazendo
      //- o login
      //logo depois ele traz os dados na variavel response
      FB.api('/me' , function(response){
        $('#status').append('<p>Olá '+response.id+' , Seja bem vindo </p>');
        console.log(response);
      });
    }

    //fucao do botao de login
    function Logar(){
      //funcao do face login
      FB.login(function(response){
        callbackMudancaStatus(response);
      });
    }
    //função botao de Logoff
    function LogarOff(){
      //funcao do face de logoff
      FB.logout(function(response){
        callbackMudancaStatus(response);
        $('#status').html('<p>Fez Logoff</p>')
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nas versões mais recentes da `API` é necessário especificar na `URL`os dados que você quer retornar. Retirei todos os comentários do código e deixei comentado somente a parte que eu precisei alterar.

```
function callbackMudancaStatus(response){
            if(response.status === 'connected'){
                $('.login').hide().fadeOut(1000);
                $('#status').append('<a onclick="LogarOff()" style="cursor:pointer"> Sair </a>');
                testAPI();
            }else if(response.status === 'not_authorized'){
                $('#status').html('<p>Por favor, faça login na pagina</p>');
            }else{
                //- $('#status').html('<p>Por favor faça login no facebook</p>');
            }
        }
        window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
              FB.init({
              appId:'{minha-id}',
              cookie:true,
              xfbml:true,
              version: 'v2.5'
          });

          FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
              callbackMudancaStatus(response);
          });
        };
        //Codigo do facebook para inicialização do 
        //JavaScript SDK
        (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        function testAPI(){
          // URL de onde quer trazer os dados
          //- /me no caso seria /eu <- o usuario que esta fazendo
          // porem nas versões mais novas do SDK é preciso especificar
          // as propriedades do objeto , isso você precisa mostrar na
          // URL , ex: /me?fields=name,email,picture, etc..
          // logo depois ele traz os dados na variavel response
          FB.api('me?fields=name,email,picture' , function(response){
            $('#status').append('<p>Olá '+response.id+' , Seja bem vindo </p>');
            console.log(response);
          },{
              //é mecessario tornar o email do usuario como publico
              // então é necessario colocar este trecho de codigo
              scope: 'publish_stream,email' 
        });
       }

        function Logar(){
          FB.login(function(response){
            callbackMudancaStatus(response);
          });
        }
        function LogarOff(){
          FB.logout(function(response){
            callbackMudancaStatus(response);
            $('#status').html('<p>Fez Logoff</p>')
          });
        }
```